# Just like there is a Shiva Purana and Vishnu Purana, is there a Purana praising Brahma?

Tags: puranas, upanishads, brahma

Title. I want a book about Brahma. It can be in the form of a Gita like Shiva Gita or Bhagavad Gita or it can be in the form of a Purana.

Thanks.

Comment: The Puranas like bramhanda, bramhakaivarta, maarkandeya, bhavishyat, vamana, braamha glorify Prjapati (Brahma), Agni and Saraswati.

Comment: There is also the brahma samhita but I do not consider that authentic so I refer to user commonman.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the Matsya-Purana (53.68-69),

> rAjaseshu cha mAhAtmyam adhikam brahmano viduh : Meaning: It is said that in the Rajasika Puranas, the glory of Brahmaa is preached.

According to the Padma-Purana (Uttara-Khanda 263, 81-84)

> Brahmanda-Purana, Brahma-vaivarta-Purana, Vhavishya- Purana, Vamana-Purana and Braahma-Purana are Rajasika.

According to some other opinion, Skanda, Padma and Agni Puranas are also termed as 'Rajasika'.

[Reference](https://shodhganga.inflibnet.ac.in/bitstream/10603/96533/7/07_chapter%203.pdf)

You could also read the Hamsa-Gita [here](https://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/hamsa-geeta-text-transliteration-word-to-word-meaning-translation-and-detailed-explanation-idk125/),  which was told by Brahmaa taking the form of a swan. There are two Hamsa-Gitas by the way, the second one being a part of the Mahabharata and included in the Gita-Ganthravali by Satish Chnadra Mukhopadhyay.

Comment: The Hamsa Gita you have linked in your answer is told by Lord **Vishnu** in the form of a Swan *to Brahma* and Sanakadi Rishis; it forms a part of Uddhava Gita in the 11th Canto of Bhagavata Purana.

Comment: Haven't heard of the Mahabharata's Hamsa Gita; is that what you were referring to?

Comment: @Surya, yes there's a Hamsa Gita in the Mahabharata too, told by Prajapati (Brahma) to the Sadhyas. You may check about it in [my answer here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/45600/17833)